# SQL Server database remote transfer - best method

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-backups

I have two databases, one on a remote server the other local. (SQL Server 2008)

The database on my local server has the entire structure setup but no data. I would like to copy the data from the remote server to my server and I am wondering the best method in which to do this.

The main issue I am experiencing is the user that I have to the remote database has limited permissions. I cannot read the stored procedures, user defined functions so when I use Import/Export wizard I do not get the schema etc. So a regular dump/restore is not working for me as it restores the tables without the Primary Keys/Foreign Keys and the stored procedures.

I'd like to do this,

```
INSERT INTO localtable SELECT * FROM remotedb.table
```

I was having issues because of the `IDENTITY` fields and I had to explicitly name all of the columns. Also I am not sure if SQL Server Management Studio allows you to use two different databases, remote and local, so I was looking for any advice.

I have also tried applications like SQL FTP and Backup and it fails because it runs out of memory (I have 16GB of memory on the machine and the DB is like 4GB). I also can use the SQL Server import/export wizard but then I don't get the schema information. I also tried SQL Compare from Red Gate and it runs into issues with the permissions. Unfortunately I do not have the time to request and gain access to a new user so I was hoping someone had a creative idea.

Comment: I think if Red Gate can't do it then you are probably in trouble since RG is super easy.  You might consider the following -- take a backup and use RG's ability to read from backups to retrieve the data.

Comment: IF you don't have permissions to access the metadata then setting up a linked server and writing out insert queries is the only option.

Comment: I linked the remote DB and I'm doing queries like so, INSERT INTO localtable (col1, col2, ... coln) SELECT col1, col2, ... coln FROM REMOTEDB.remotedb.remotetable;  This is rather tedious and I find that SQL not letting me turn off the protection for inserts into the identity fields so I could just do a * and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can definitely use SQL Server Backups for this. It will not run out of memory. If it does please tell us the message (because likely you are misinterpreting it). This is the fastest possible and the most complete solution.
2. You can tell the export wizard to also script the schema. It is hidden under "advanced" somewhere (terrible UI). But the script will be extremely big and I know of no way to execute it.
3. You can drop all schema objects except PKs in the target database. Then you can use remote queries to copy all the data over. You will not get any problems with foreign keys and identity columns if you drop the beforehand. After you are done you can recreate all those objects. It is probably best if you use a transaction for all of this because that way you get consistent source data from a point-in-time.

Comment: Just as comparison - I am backing up my main personal database (around 800gb, half full) daily and the server has 16gb memory only.

Comment: Yeah. Backups do not take significant amounts of memory.

Comment: I do not have BACKUP_DATABASE permissions with my user :D